# Узнать к какой таблице применяем пользовательскую функцию postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

пишу свою функцию для postgre на языке sql:

```
SELECT f(name) FROM table;
```

как в теле функции узнать, для какой таблицы была вызвана функция (определить, что применяем именно к table)?

Comment: Передать имя таблицы вторым параметром в функцию.

Comment: есть ли какие-то вызовы или специальные команды sql, чтобы узнать название?

Comment: Во `from` можно указать несколько таблиц: `from tableA, tableB, tableC`. | `select` можно вызывать без `from`: например, `select 4;`, `select f('value');`. Так что...